# Consequences of cancelling a Tier 5 GAE UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, cancellations, working-visas, visa-cancellation

I am a non-EU citizen. I have signed a contract for a summer internship in the UK and the company is going to sponsor a Tier 5 GAE visa for me (so at some point I will have to go to an appointment to a visa center to apply for it).

It is possible that I will have to cancel that contract due to external circumstances and will not use that visa. Will there be any negative consequences for my future visa applications if I cancel an appointment/cancel the process after an appointment/cancel the approved visa (depending on how far in the process I will decide not to take the job), assuming that I do that cancellation correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The company probably won't be happy with you, but No - not using a visa that you were granted will not have any negative impact. A visa is just being granted permission to visit the country. It's not an obligation to do so. The visa was paid for either way, so the government is happy. The worst that you may see is being asked why you didn't go if you do apply for a visa in the future. Even better, you've actually been given a visa so that may make things a bit easier applying in the future.